# Installing GRASS on Linux

Tags: python, grass-gis, linux, amazon-web-services

I am installing GRASS on Linux using source code and the ./configure file to create a standalone python script. I have been following instructions and installing relevant code like proj4 and GDAL and linux libs. I am getting this error now which I am unsure how to

```
  configure: error: *** Unable to locate TIFF includes.
```

I am not sure if there is a yum package that would fix this problem. I am new to linux and am using Amazon Linux for AWS Workspace that has yum as package manager, which seems to be lesser used than apt.

Can you help regarding this error or a better way to install GRASS on Amazon Linux?

Comment: Generalyl this kind of error appears when the configure script does not find a headers files (here those of ``libtiff``). I never used amazon linux, but usually the headers are in a specific package whose name ends with *dev* or *devel*. Try to find him ``yum search "libtiff"``.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it has entirely fixed it, but in the end I just ran ./configure to ignore various settings so that they no longer became an issue:

```
  CFLAGS="-g -Wall" ./configure --with-tiff=no --with-png=no --with-sqlite=no 
  --with-opengl=no --with-fftw=no --with-cairo=no --with-freetype=no
```

Comment: Yes, you do not need libtiff here - all is done via GDAL nowadays.